How can I modify the Woocommerce product entry form page to preload dropdown lists of attributes and values?
The Woocommerce product entry page creates a product_attributes div containing a a select dropdown for Add Existing attributes. But the existing attributes and their values aren't populated until the user goes to the Attributes tab and puts focus in the select box.
I can see this makes sense for sites with many attributes.
But for my site with only 3 attributes, only one of which is routinely used, every product entered involves a brief wait for the attributes to load in, and then a second wait for the existing 5 values of that standard attribute.
In general the site is reasonably fast,but I haven't managed to optimise sufficiently for the admin wait for the dropdown lists to not be noticeable and annoying. I tried changing the attributes to load using Ajax, but if anything that was slightly slower.
I would like to load the attributes and their values with the rest of the product entry page, so that by the time a user has entered title, description etc, the attribute dropdowns are ready for use.
I'm not sure where to start because I don't know what is delaying the load of these dropdown lists or how to control them.  I already have a custom plugin for other tweaks to the site but I am struggling to find information about the backend entry of attributes, rather than displaying them on the public site. Any suggestions very welcome.
I am using Woocommerce 8.83 and Wordpress 6.53

What you describe is not usual.
When there are too many variations for a variable product, you need to increase the Ajax Variation Threshold, like:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', function( $threshold ){
    return 100; // Default threshold value is set to 30 variations
}, 1000, 1 );

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

If increasing the Ajax Variation Threshold doesn't solve the issue, maybe this is related to your theme own customizations, to some third party plugin or to a caching issue...
What you can try to do is:

Make a database backup via a backup plugin or via your hosting (mandatory)…
Disable the cache (if any)…
Disable all plugins except WooCommerce…
Add "Storefront" theme and enable it…
Browse your variable product to see if you are still getting this issue…

If the issue is solved, that means that your theme, a plugin or the cache was making trouble.
To find out the culprit, you need to re-enable back your initial configuration, step by step, browsing in between your variable product.

Start by switching back to your theme.
Enable back plugins one by one.
Enable back your cache

To revert everything back like before, set back your initial database from the backup.

I'm sorry I missed this reply earlier.
We have only 3 variations with 5 values each, so a total of 15 variation values. It's definitely not the number of variations.  (I did try your code, but it didn't make a difference, as I expected because we don't have or need 1000 variations.)
I have tried the standard debugging steps listed.
I'm fairly sure that the issue is related to the size of our database (we have about 19,000 products to date) and possibly also ATUM inventory, but we can't really reduce our database size or abandon our inventory software.

That's why I wanted to know if it was possible, instead of optimising further to speed up the load of the variations during data entry, to PRELOAD them when the main editor page loads.  So I can open an editor tab, or a few tabs, and when I start putting data in, the whole form is already loaded.
My question is not about optimisation or large numbers of variations.  It's about changing how the editor page load order works so the variation list loads at the start, rather than half-way through product entry. I'm sorry that wasn't clear, and I do appreciate the effort!

WooCommerce can handle much more products than that, and as you say you have only 15 variations on your variable products, which should not make trouble as you describe… So the issue could be related to your theme, or a plugin like for example Elementor (that is known to slow down things). Also, your hosting could be involved in the issue. Normally, a variable product with 15 variations should be charged instantly... Did you check your browser console for JavaScript errors?

Yes, I know that it can handle more products: I went back over everything we have loading again, and made some tweaks to the theme that have speeded the site up a bit in general.  I'm not using Elementor.  I have contacted the developer of Atum to ask if there are any optimisations I could make to my Atum multi-inventory to speed that up, since I do have a couple of slow queries showing.

The site is not slow. But the central issue remains: that in order to enter a product, I have to make a choice from a series of three javascript-driven dropdowns, one after the other.  Each one has a noticeable load time, and it would be really nice if that load time could be preloaded rather than having the user wait at each step, even if the wait is only a couple of seconds.
